# How to make Drupal 6 print Region DIV wrappers

Tags: html, drupal, regions

I'm using context to print blocks into a region.  However, I'd like to have the region print wrapper DIVs around the blocks of the given area.  I know this is possible with region.tpl.php in Drupal 7.  I can't seem to figure out the best way in Drupal 6.

```
 <div class="{region classes i.e. sidebarleft}">
      <div class="{block 1}"></div>
      <div class="{block 2}"></div>
      <div class="{block 3}"></div>
      <div class="{block 4}"></div>
 </div>
```

However, currently it prints like this:

```
<a id="context-block-region-right" class="context-block-region">Right Sidebar</a>
      // the previous anchor tags is hidden
      <div id="block-block-82" class="clear-block block block-block">
           <h2>Community Navigation Block</h2>
                <div class="content">
                <div id="community-landing-navigation-menu">
                <div class="joinCommunityBox">
                <div class="community-landing-pagePanelWrapperSideBar">
                <div class="community-landing-pagePanelWrapperSideBar">
           <a id="context-block-block-82" class="context-block editable edit-community_contexts"></a>
 </div>
 </div>
```

I wish it would print a region wrapper tag around ALL of that...

Also, I want to keep my page.tpl.php clean of extra wrapper tags.  It would be better if we could preprocess regions to print a wrapper tag.

Comment: I'm afraid in Drupal 6 putting extra wrapper tags in `page.tpl.php` *is* the preferred (maybe only) way to accomplish this.

Comment: I figured it out...

The answer is actually borrowed from zen.  If you click the link below, several preprocess functions are rendering a new region template.  Then, blocks are collected into that region, and printed.

http://drupal.org/node/223440#comment-5304866

Comment: I stand corrected :) Thanks for the link. You should post that link with a small description as the answer it's likely to be quite useful to someone in the future

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out... The answer is actually borrowed from zen. If you click the link below, several 'preprocess functions' are rendering a new region template. Then, blocks are collected into that region, and printed.

http://www.drupal.org/node/223440#comment-5304866

It works great, and is going to go production soon.